# Reflect changes in admin page Django

Tags: django

I have a model and originally it had these attributes

```
First Name
Last Name
Email
```

I altered the model to include an additional attribue : Address , now it looks like this

```
First Name
Last Name
Email
Address
```

I am using MySQL database and the changes are reflected in the table in the database , however the changes are **not reflected** in Django admin as the tables does not have a new column called Address.

I know it has something to do with overriding the admin template in Django but i cant seems to be able to do it , can someone guide me

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to override admin templates to show this.  Can you add your admin class definition to the question?  That's where you control what fields are shown in the various parts of the admin.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I am very new to Django , i am not sure where my admin class definition is

Comment: In order for a model class to show up in the admin, you must have registered it.  Something like admin.site.register(Person) or admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin).  PersonAdmin would be your admin class.  If you didn't specify a custom admin class, you'd get the default behavior, which shows all fields on the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `admin.py` file in your app directory, there will be a subclass of ModelAdmin that is registered for this model. Make sure the address field is listed in either the `fields` or `fieldsets` property of this class, and make sure it is *not* listed in the `exclude` list on this class.

REF: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/